# SqlConnection namespace not found

Tags: c#, .net

I'm building up a website using C#, whenever I try this

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection ();
```

I get the error that `SqlConnection` namespace isn't found, but when I do this

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
```

it works.

Tried to add reference to `System.Data.SqlClient`, but couldn't find it the references lists even though `System.Data` is added assembly in the `web.config` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: Ensure you're referencing `System.Data` not `System.Data.SqlClient`

Then add

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

To your namespaces

Comment: @user2962142 Download [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/)  and things like these you won't even notice.

Comment: ops, i got an error, where im supposed to to add the using statement in the webpage ? i mean like inside the code blocks ? since im building a .net webpage

Comment: You use it in your `c#` file, what are you developing the web page in? MVC? Also can you paste the error please

Comment: No ordinary ASP.NET Razor webpages with the extension .cshtml, if i do "@using System.Data.sqlclient;" i get error saying "} expected".

Comment: Yeah that error is unrelated... Post a new question for it... include the lines of code that is causing you the issue in your new post too... :)

Comment: I'm using VS 2022.  I ended up installing from NuGet, as mentioned below for users of VS Code mentioned.  "System.Data.SqlClient" by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

As the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) states, `SqlConnection` exists in the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace, inside the `System.Data` assembly.

A class's namespace and assembly name do not always match.

Since `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` works for you, you must already have a reference to `System.Data`. To fix the error, add a `using` statement for `System.Data.SqlClient` to the top of your file.

If you're using Visual Studio, you can right-click on `SqlConnection` and let Visual Studio find the correct namespace and add a `using` for you. This works for any class where you already have a reference to the assembly that contains it.

Comment: I use "Visual Studio Code", dotnet add package System.Data.SqlClient and dotnet add package System.Data, but not found System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

Answer (score 1):

if you have this error in .net core , you shoud install  System.Data.SqlClient  Nuget package